# Why escape_string isn't work?

Tags: php, sql

I cannot understand why `escape_string` is not found?

```
static public function find_by_id($id) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM bicycles";
    $sql .= "WHERE id = '" . self::$database->escape_string($id) . "'";
    $obj_array = self::find_by_sql($sql);

    if (!empty($obj_array)) {
       return array_shift($obj_array);
    } else {
       return fasle;
    }
}
```

Warning message here:

[image]

Comment: Post your code as plain text, not an image. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for code formatting help.

Comment: What is the type of `$database`?

Comment: You shouldn't escape strings in database queries, you should use prepared statements with parameters. So forget about that function and do things the right way.

Comment: BTW, you need a space between `bicycles` and `WHERE`.

Comment: And `fasle` should be `false`.

Comment: oh yeah... I'm so silly. Thank you very much.

Comment: In your image, it was just your IDE warning you. It probably doesn't know the datatype of `self::$database`, so it doesn't know that it has an `escape_string` method. You need to add a documentation comment with the datatype.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This message is just a warning from your IDE, it's not a program error.

You need to tell your IDE that `self::$database` contains a `mysqli` object, so it knows what methods are available. Above the declaration of the property, add a documentation comment:

```
/**
 * @var mysqli
 */
private static $database;
```

Answer (score -3):

It is not clear where the `$database` object is coming from.

It is most likely that you can use `mysql_escape_string` in your case.

Documentation can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php).

Comment: The `mysql` extension is obsolete, you should never recommend it.

Comment: PHP is obsolete at best :)